# How to get last 7 days of data for a user using a SQL query depending on the date passed in a tuple?

Tags: python, sql, date, hive, jupyter-notebook

I am running a sql query inside my python script to get some data. This is my sql query:

```
sql_query=(""" SELECT date,
                      name,
                      sum(some_value) as Total_Value

            FROM table_name 
            WHERE (SUBSTRING(date,1,8), name) IN {}
            GROUP BY date,name

""").format(tuple_passed)
```

The passed tuple is in this form

```
(('20191001', 'mike'),('20191001', 'julia'),......)
```

The date in the table is in the form (it was stored as a string not date time format in that DB):

```
202002051600
```

while tuple date is like this:

```
20200205
```

That is why i am using the **SUBSTRING** function.

The issue is that for the sql query depending on the date in the tuple for a particular name, i want to query the last 7 days of data (from the date mentioned in the tuple) for that particular name from the table. I am not sure how to do that in sql?
The main issue is that the date passed for each name from the tuple is different each time. So for each name the last 7 days queried from the DB would be different depending on the date passed from the tuple.

The tuple data is coming from a csv (which indirectly came from another DB).

So if my tuple data is like this:

```
20200111 Mike
20200120 Julia
20200211 Bob
20200219 Mike
20200301 Bob
20200411 Mike
```

So based on the date here for Mike`s each date the query should get the **some_value** from the DB for last 7 days for each of these dates **"20200111"**, **"20200219"** and **"20200411"**.

I tried using

```
DATE_ADD(dt, -7)
```

in the **WHERE clause** in the query. But that is not working properly to get the required data.

Comment: . . Hive and SQL Server are quite different.  Please tag only with the databse you are really using.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the DB tag.